# How to SELECT specific characters using SQL in SQL server database

Tags: sql-server

How can I select only information that start with a #?

I have a table with 5 columns and in one of the columns i.e. the comments column there is information like:

```
#2345 Changed by Mark

Paul changed ticket number #5923

Someone changed ticket number #5823 and #9333

#3555 is missing from the list, can only see #5789, #9000 and #4568
```

In the sample of 4 rows above, I want my select statement to return only ticket numbers as shown below:

comments

```
 #2345 

 #5923

 #5823,  #9333

 #5789, #9000, #4568
```

Someone said regular expressions can do the work for me but I am fresh graduate and have never seen such before. Can you help me please??

Comment: This is going to be a headache in SQL Server, because it has weak native regex support.  Do you have to do this in your database?  What about a language like Java?

Comment: Not really a pain if you can use CLR functions

Comment: @MartinSmith I am using powershell to query the database but like I said, am still new to this Dev world, its very painful to me now. Can you please help?

Comment: @Immortal i added new answer it returns numeric numbers with # only. Any numeric number without # will not return

Comment: @Immortal Did you get that expected result Add your table Name Instead of #TempTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use this script below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
Drop table #TempTable

CREATE TABLE [dbo].#TempTable(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](1000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT [dbo].#TempTable ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (1, N'#2345 Changed by Mark #111111,767677,33333,#5656 vbvb')
GO
INSERT [dbo].#TempTable ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (2, N'Paul changed ticket number #5923,5555555 464646 #010101,5555544rrr,wwww AND #4 ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].#TempTable ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (3, N'Someone changed ticket number #5823 and #9333,7777')
GO
INSERT [dbo].#TempTable ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (4, N'#3555 is missing from the list, can only see #5789, #9000 and #4568')
GO


;WITH cte
AS
(
 SELECT ID,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS TablesData
            FROM (
                SELECT ID,CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(Value, ' ', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS TablesData
                FROM #TempTable
                ) AS A
            CROSS APPLY TablesData.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
)
,Final
AS
(
SELECT ID,TablesData FROM 
(
SELECT ID, Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS TablesData,CHARINDEX('#',Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)')) AS Data2
            FROM (
                SELECT ID,CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(TablesData, ',', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS TablesData
                FROM cte
                ) AS A
            CROSS APPLY TablesData.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
            )DT
            WHERE dt.Data2 <>0

)

SELECT DISTINCT ID
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + CAST(TablesData AS VARCHAR(50))
            FROM Final i
            WHERE i.ID = o.ID
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS ColumnsWith#ValuesOnly
FROM Final o
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the required fields from your database table using SQL, then perform regex operations on the result in another language such as c++, php etc. when outputting your result to the client

Comment: am not familiar with these languages maybe in power-shell? Do you have any example?

Comment: Power shell alone won't do the trick, at least that's what I think.
According to my knowledge, SQL is just for querying data from RDBMS, much of the complex stuff is handled by other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

First Create Function To extract #numeric values

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
(
@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^#0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^#0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO
```

By Using Below Code we can Extract the numeric values

```
Declare @TempTable TABLE(ID Int Identity,Value varchar(1000))
INSERT INTO @TempTable
          SELECT '#2345 Changed by Mark'                                                
UNION ALL SELECT 'Paul changed ticket number #5923'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Someone changed ticket number #5823 and #9333'
UNION ALL SELECT '#3555 is missing from the list, can only see #5789, #9000 and #4568'

 SELECT ID, 
 RIGHT(LTRIM(REPLACE(Value,'#',' ,#')),LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(Value,'#',' ,#'))))-1)AS Value FROM
 (
 SELECT ID,dbo.udf_GetNumeric(Value) AS Value From @TempTable
 )Dt
```

If you need to extract Numeric values Instead of pre-fixed wirh '#' Symbol

```
SELECT ID, 
 REPLACE(RIGHT(LTRIM(REPLACE(Value,'#',' ,#')),LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(Value,'#',' ,#'))))-1),'#',' ')AS Value FROM
 (
 SELECT ID,dbo.udf_GetNumeric(Value) AS Value From @TempTable
 )Dt
```

OutPut

```
ID  Value
----------
1   #2345
2   #5923
3   #5823 ,#9333
4   #3555 ,#5789 ,#9000 ,#4568
```

Comment: how would your solution work If I do have over 1000 rows like this?

Comment: Use Your table Name instead of ''@TempTable ''
 SELECT ID, 
 RIGHT(LTRIM(REPLACE(Value,'#',' ,#')),LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(Value,'#',' ,#'))))-1)AS Value FROM
 (
 SELECT ID,dbo.udf_GetNumeric(Value) AS Value From @TempTable
 )Dt

Comment: Yes its working now, however it is now selecting every numeric number in the column instead of selecting only the ones that start with # for example: #5923. How can I modify this?

Comment: if you want only numeric instead of prefixed with # ?

Comment: I want numeric numbers with # only. Any numeric number without # should not be returned

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
Drop table #TempTable

CREATE TABLE [dbo].#TempTable(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](1000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT [dbo].#TempTable ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (1, N'#2345 Changed by Mark #111111,767677,33333,#5656 vbvb')
GO
INSERT [dbo].#TempTable ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (2, N'Paul changed ticket number #5923,5555555 464646 #010101,5555544rrr,wwww AND #4 ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].#TempTable ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (3, N'Someone changed ticket number #5823 and #9333,7777')
GO
INSERT [dbo].#TempTable ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (4, N'#3555 is missing from the list, can only see #5789, #9000 and #4568')
GO


;WITH cte
AS
(
 SELECT ID,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS TablesData
            FROM (
                SELECT ID,CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(Value, ' ', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS TablesData
                FROM #TempTable
                ) AS A
            CROSS APPLY TablesData.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
)
,Final
AS
(
SELECT ID,TablesData FROM 
(
SELECT ID, Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS TablesData,CHARINDEX('#',Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)')) AS Data2
            FROM (
                SELECT ID,CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(TablesData, ',', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS TablesData
                FROM cte
                ) AS A
            CROSS APPLY TablesData.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
            )DT
            WHERE dt.Data2 <>0

)

SELECT DISTINCT ID
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + CAST(TablesData AS VARCHAR(50))
            FROM Final i
            WHERE i.ID = o.ID
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS ColumnsWith#ValuesOnly
FROM Final o
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

OutPut

```
ID  ColumnsWith#ValuesOnly
---------------------------
1    #2345, #111111, #5656
2    #5923, #010101, #4
3    #5823, #9333
4    #3555, #5789, #9000, #4568
```